# using ONLY ActiveMQ get file from network folder to queue

Tags: messaging, activemq-classic, apache-camel

Our organization is moving towards a new case management system.  One of the functions that it has is the ability to publish XML files when certain conditions are met.  I have that portion all set up and I get an XML document in a network folder.

Disclaimer:  I have no knowledge ActiveMQ and/or Camel - complete newbie!!

I have recently set up ActiveMQ on a server.  I believe it is working correctly because I can send from the example.A queue and it creates example.B queue with the message in it.

I have a camel.xml file that I have put the following piece of code:

```
<route>
    <description>Leslie Odyssey Route</description>
    <from uri="file://servername.domain.gov/MetroFileDrop"/>
    <to uri="activemq:queue:Odyssey.Queue"/>
</route>
```

Can someone tell me what more I need to do in order to get the XML file that is put in the MetroFileDrop folder moved to the Odyssey.Queue?

Thanks,
leslie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the issue was with the UNC it should be `\\\\servername.domain.gov\\MetroFileDrop`

Comment: You you mark this question as answered then, now that you have resolved it

Answer (score 2):

if you are deploying this to ActiveMQ, then make sure the following is setup..

- import the camel.xml file at the end of your /conf/activemq.xml file to enable it when AMQ starts up

  ```
  <import resource="camel.xml"/>
  ```
- in your /conf/camel.xml file, make sure you setup the ActiveMQ component properly

  ```
  <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
      <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
  </bean>
  ```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I already have.  I reposted my question because I think it has to with network authentication.

Comment: yep, that is a different issue altogether...you should post details about the error, etc.